# Why is the following limit operation valid?

Tags: limits

Towards the end of the lecture (Found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v25gg2qJYE) at 46:15), the following equality is stated:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac1n)^n = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}ln((1+\frac1n)^n)}$

It was earlier proved that $lim_{n \to \infty}ln((1+\frac1n)^n) = 1$, so the above would then give a definition for $e$. However, i don't understand why the above statement is valid. By the definition of $e$ it's obvious that $e^{log(x)} = x$, however here the statement is instead $e^{\lim_{n \to something} log(somethingelse)}$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+(1/n))^n=e^{\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+(1/n))^n)}$.  Now you can move the $\ln$ part inside the limit because natural log is continuous.

Comment: @homegrown I'm sorry but that went partially over my head, as my textbook only gives a very basic introduction to continuity. Why on earth can the ln move inside the limit just because it is continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$ is the definition of $e$ (if we know that this sequence is convergent).

So using the continuity of $\ln$ function we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln(1+\frac1n)^n=\ln\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac1n)^n=\ln e=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know a lot about continuity. Is it possible for you to update your answer with details as to why $ln$ being continuous allows you to move it around the limit?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous (in an interval around point $x$) and you have convergence $x_n\to x$, then by the continuity you have convergence $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.